# final method in java

Tags: java

I got the question in an interview, `can final method override....?`

I said YES. Interviewer has got strange gesture. What is wrong with it? Grammatically it is correct answer, I guess. final methods can override, but final method cannot be overridden.
Was my answer correct?

I found some people are interested to reopen this question.

Comment: A `final` method cannot _be overriden_. Perhaps just a misunderstanding due to interview nerves.

Comment: Maybe the interviewer thought they said "can a final method be overridden" ? Only the interviewer would be able to tell you. Perhaps send them (or the HR) a polite email asking

Comment: I think that person did not understood you. He probably was asking about your second option. But do not worry, if he did not understood, you do not want to work with them. ;-).

Comment: Belongs to english.stackexchange.com maybe?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If his English was bad, then you should've tried to clarify what he means. Communication is a very important aspect of building software.

Apart from that:

- final methods can override other methods
- final methods cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 4):

[**final (Java)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29)

> In the Java programming language, the final keyword is used in several
>   different contexts to define an entity which cannot later be changed.
>
> A final method cannot be overridden by subclasses. This is used to
>   prevent unexpected behavior from a subclass altering a method that may
>   be crucial to the function or consistency of the class.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there was a bit of a misunderstanding; if they genuinely asked the question as you phrased it, it is unclear which of the following they were asking of you:

- an existing `final` method ***cannot*** be overridden
- the override of an existing non-`final` method ***can*** be made `final` to prevent further overriding.

Answer (score 1):

It was easier for me to think of it like this: Whatever you declare as final means that it is 100% complete in functionality and no one else should ever be allowed to subclass it, extend it etc.

Of course you can mark an overriding function as final. But you can't override a final function.

Answer (score 0):

A final class cannot be subclassed,
A final method cannot be overridden by subclasses,
A final variable can only be initialized once

Answer (score 0):

Static methods and final methods cannot be overridden in java.